# Cannot run React Native project because of unknown type error

Tags: react-native, typeerror

i dont know how to solve this error could someone please help i dont even know where the error is since the location of the error is unknown for my react native expo project

````
This error is located at:
    in Unknown
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View
    in Unknown (created by App)
    in App (at Auth/index.tsx:106)
    in Wrapper (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in DevAppContainer (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent)```
````

Comment: Hi Ankita,
I think the error you have pasted here is not enough.
Can you please add a screenshot of the RED error screen? or maybe more of the error showing in your bundler

Comment: code of the View would be nice too

Comment: Highly possible that an error happens here in App (at Auth/index.tsx:106)